# How to display different datsets in Flatlist. React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have two different datasets that i'm adding to different states. I want to display them both in a Flatlist but don't know how to access the second set of data.

I'm fetching data from an API request then setting it to state:

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState([]);
const [data2, setData2] = useState([]);
```

I merged data together:

```
const finalData = [...data1, ...data2]
```

My Flatlist:

```
<FlatList 
  data={finalData}
  renderItem={_renderItem}>
</FlatList>
```

My _renderItem:

```
const _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <View>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: item.image }} 
    />
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', alignSelf: 'center', paddingLeft: 10 }}>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text>{item.username}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

I'd like for my Image to come from data1 and the rest of the data from data2

I've tried looking into Sectionlist but got stuck with that too.

Appreciate any help, thanks!!

Comment: im assuming your data1 and data2 are arrays of objects? and how exactly is data1 related to data2?

Comment: yes, both arrays of objects and both coming from different api endpoints

Comment: whats the common between to api object? as in data1 object should have something common with data2 object right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an item that something of it is from first api and rest of data are from other api, you are be able to easily do something like followings approach:

```js
  const [mergedData, setMergedData] = React.useState([]);
  /*
  You are be able to get both of data from 
  server in one block or consider two separated function for each of them (I consider first way and second way will need to a state variable more).
  In this semicodes assume firstData is information data and secondData is your images.
  */
  const firstData = await getFirstData();
  const secondData = await getSecondData();
  /*
  Both above arrays have same length
  */
  const mData = firstData.map((data, index) => {
    return {
      ...data,
      image: secondData[index].image,
    };
  });

  setMergedData (mData);
```